# Cant write in a file to save a score on a game

Tags: python, file

I am using:

```
text_file = open('files/highscoresnake.txt', 'w')
word = str(score)
text_file.write(word)
```

to save a highscore on a game.
however this does nothing to the text file

---

anyone know why?

Comment: Yep, you don't `close()` the file so the write buffer isn't flushed to the file

Comment: @roganjosh thanks pls post as answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file when you're done. Try `text_file.close()` afterward.

Better yet, use `with`:

```
with open('files/highscoresnake.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(word)
```

`with` will close the file after you exit that block of code.

Comment: Thank you joshua

Comment: @Glitchd anytime!